# Angular 5 Header value is not append correctly

Tags: java, angular, spring, cors

I am appending the headers in angular service request but the value is not appending correctly, I was created one Interceptor to add header like below

```
@Injectable()
export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    // Clone the request to add the new header
    const clonedRequest = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('tenantId', 'r 123') });

    // Pass the cloned request instead of the original request to the next handle
    return next.handle(clonedRequest);
  }
}
```

While i am sending to server the value not appending correctly, it's showin like in below picture, the value 'r 123' is not appending, How do i solve it?

[headers image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YXM3.png)

[image]

Comment: can you confirm first your interceptor is called or not ?? if called then try to remove space here 'r 123' between r and digits and then try

Comment: req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('tenantId', 'r 123') }) is also correct

Comment: The request is a [CORS pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). The server needs to respond with the appropriate [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) headers.

Comment: @georgeawg yes, it;s preflighted request how do i solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `AddHeaderInterceptor` in you `app.module.ts`.

```
// ...
providers: [
    // ...
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AddHeaderInterceptor, multi: true },
    //...
]
```

Comment: i already added this, But its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try these

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'header1':  'test',
  'header2': 'test',
 })
};
req.clone({ headers: httpOptions) });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Still getting same error.

Comment: which error you got?

Comment: he bro, header is not show option method (these method is preflight request ) when these request is success then again hit another request get or post yiu can check header in these request

Comment: Can you send me the example of preflight request, How to handle it?

Comment: backend server set CORS origin header that accept all types of request.

Answer (score 0):

try this for angular 5,this might work,

```
    const clonedRequest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: { 'tenantId', 'r 123'}  
    });
```

Comment: I changed, Still getting same issue.

Comment: ok did you check first your interceptor method is called or not ??try to put console.log('something') inside interceptor method and confirm this.

Comment: Yes, it's printing, But still not appending the value, and I removed the space in string also.